# Move JLabel in GridLayout java swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to move a Robot represented by a JLabel into a GridLayout.
The move is made but the display of the JLabel is only done for the final finishing square.
I would like to see the move from box to box. How can I do ?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;

// Robot

public class Robot extends Case implements Serializable {
    private ImageIcon imageRobot;
    private Color couleur;

    public Robot () {
        imageRobot = new ImageIcon("./assets/balle.png");
        setIcon(imageRobot);
    }

    public void seDeplacer (JPanel panel, Vector<Case> listeDeCases) {      
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            LayoutManager layout = panel.getLayout();   
            try {   Thread.sleep(1000);
            panel.remove(panel.getComponent(i));
            panel.add(this, i);
            panel.doLayout();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void detruire () {

    }

    public void setCouleur (Color couleur) {
        this.couleur=couleur;
    }

    public Color getCouleur () {
        return this.couleur;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        try {   Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Don't do this on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Your GUI can't be repainted because this code is blocking it.

Use `javax.swing.Timer` (not to be confused with any other `Timer`) to set an event for the next time robot needs to be moved. You will need to keep track of state outside of local variables.

Comment: I try to use javax.swing.Timerbut i think i don't use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
import javax.swing.Timer;

// Robot

public class Robot extends Case implements Serializable {
    private ImageIcon imageRobot;
    private Color couleur;

    public Robot () {
        imageRobot = new ImageIcon("./assets/balle.png");
        setIcon(imageRobot);
    }

    public void seDeplacer (JPanel panel) {
        Robot currentRoot = this;
            int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
              ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        panel.remove(panel.getComponent(i));
                        panel.add(currentRoot, i);
                        panel.doLayout();   
                        }
                  }
              };
              new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

    }

    public void detruire () {

    }

    public void setCouleur (Color couleur) {
        this.couleur=couleur;
    }

    public Color getCouleur () {
        return this.couleur;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `int i` and indeed the for-loop needs to be outside the `actionPerformed` method. `i` could be a field of the anonymous inner class. The `Timer` needs to fire five times.